# LibGDX Android launch

Tags: java, android, libgdx, launch

I couldn't figure out how to launch my LibGDX class (which extends Game and works perfectly) on Android. I've found something with 'initialize(Screen, config)', but that requires the Activity to extend 'AndroidApplication' and if it extends 'AndroidApplication' it crashes immediately.

So the question is, how to properly launch LibGDX Game class on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is any AndroidApplication method which is being called, you NEED to call the initialize(Game, config) method, otherwise it will crash and throws error.

This is, how it should look:

```
public class Main extends AndroidApplication {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new TP1(), config);
    }
}
```